# How to combine more than one models in JBuilder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

The structure I need is:

```
[{model}, {model}, {other model}, ...] # for jquery ui autocomplete
```

How can I build this structure with JBuilder? For render array they has array! method, that accepts one argument - collection. But I have more than one collection. Why it's so complicated?

Answer (score 1):

I used the method `child!` to solve the problem.

```
  json.models do 
    @model1s.each do |m1|   
      json.child!{|json| json.partial! m1,as :Model1}        
    end

    @model2s.each do |m2|   
      json.child!{|json| json.partial! m2,as :Model2}   
    end
  end
```

Get more from [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/jbuilder/Jbuilder:child!)